# Proving that something is a multiplicative norm

Tags: abstract-algebra, normed-spaces

Obviously, we need to show that the 2 conditions for a multiplicative norm are satisfied for $N$. Here is the first:

If $N(\alpha)=0$, it means that $a^2+2b^2=0$ for $a, b\in\mathbb{Z}$, which is only possible when both $a=0$ and $b=0$. Thus, $N(\alpha)=0$ iff $\alpha=0$. Not too bad.

The problem I am having is with the second condition, which is to show that $N(\alpha\beta)=N(\alpha)\cdot N(\beta)$

Comment: That's a simple computation.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Dzoooks is it that simple? I am just not seeing it. Maybe just a little off today...

Comment: @batman have you tried just computing it? Step by step

Comment: sometimes you wrote $\sqrt5$ and sometimes $\sqrt2$ !?

Comment: Voting to close as unclear. Why are you not telling what $\alpha$ is, and what $N$ means?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen:  it appears OP deleted much material when editing, including definition of $N$

Comment: That is likely, @J.W.Tanner. And I can guess what norm this is supposed to be. Anyway, that doesn't change the fact that the current version is cryptic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$N(a+ib\sqrt 2)N(c+id\sqrt 2)=(a^2+2b^2)(c^2+2d^2)=(ac)^2+4(bd)^2+2(bc)^2+2(ad)^2,$$ and 
$$N((a+ib\sqrt 2)(c+id\sqrt 2))=N((ac-2bd)+i(ad+bc)\sqrt 2)=(ac-2bd)^2+2(ad+bc)^2=N(a+ib\sqrt 2)N(c+id\sqrt 2) $$

Answer (score 0):

This norm is the same as the square of the modulus of $a+ib\sqrt2$ as a complex number,

which is known to be [multiplicative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Complex_numbers).

$|a+ib\sqrt2|^2=(a+ib\sqrt2)(a-ib\sqrt2)=a^2+2b^2=N(a+ib\sqrt2)$, and

so $N(\alpha)\cdot N(\beta)=|\alpha|^2|\beta|^2=|\alpha\beta|^2=N(\alpha)N(\beta).$